# Add foreign key to the existing table diesel Rust

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I have two existing tables: user_table and post. I need to make the relation between these two tables i.e. add `user_id` to the post table.
I have the following migration

```
ALTER TABLE post
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_post_user_id
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES user_table (id);
```

Schema

```
diesel::table! {
    post (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        title -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        content -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        date -> Timestamp,
        user_id -> Int4,
    }
}

diesel::table! {
    user_table (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        username -> Varchar,
        email -> Varchar,
        password -> Varchar,
    }
}

diesel::joinable!(post -> user_table (user_id));

diesel::allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
    post,
    user_table,
);
```

These two lines I added by myself

```
diesel::joinable!(post -> user_table (user_id));
user_id -> Int4
```

My post and user models

```
#[derive(Queryable, Identifiable, Associations)]
#[belongs_to(User)]
#[table_name="post"]
pub struct Post {
    pub id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub content: String,
    pub user_id: i32
}

#[derive(Queryable, Identifiable, Clone)]
#[table_name="user_table"]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i32,
    pub username: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
}
```

SQL queries for creating tables

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE post (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR,
    content VARCHAR,
    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

I am getting a migration error

> column "user_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

I am new to the backend development and I am stuck with this problem.
Would be grateful for any support

Comment: Could you show CREATE TABLE SQL queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in with your migration:

```
ALTER TABLE post
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_post_user_id
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES user_table (id);
```

This basically says create a foreign key constraint on the **existing** column `user_id` that references the other table, but the `user_id` column does not exist. You can fix that by adding a `ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN user_id INTEGER;` to your migration before creating the foreign key.

Comment: So I need two migrations?
1. For creating user_id field
2. To make this field related to the user id

Comment: No you can do that in a single migration. Just put both statements into the same migration file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest directly adding `user_id`

To `posts` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE post (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR,
    content VARCHAR,
    user_id INT,
    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

The FK constraint will work if this schema is set.

Remember to drop migrations ( drop the tables) and re-run the migrations.

Be careful if you have some data in your tables. If you drop a table data will be lost.